# How to find selectionStart in CKEditor like Javascript selectionStart

Tags: ckeditor5

CKEditor getFirstPosition() return the line count and position of selection. But I only want to get position of selection like JS. How can I do? Any other Idea?

In CKEditor5 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzWr.png)

In JS selctionStart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVD2.png)

So, I want to get selectionStart Value like JS in CKEditor 5

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you expand it a bit?

Comment: Sorry for my Engilsh. Reinmar. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the positions in CKEditor 5 to be a single integer offset from the beginning of the document. Just like natively in a plain-text textarea.

While that'd be possible to calculate such an offset in CKEditor 5 (by summing up the lengths of all elements that precede the selection), that does not make much sense. In CKEditor 5 positions are represented by arrays of offsets. This representation makes finding the location of a position in the tree easy and fast. With a singular offset that'd be complicated and slow.

The [concept of positions an offsets is explained in the documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#indexes-and-offsets) and I'd recommend changing the way of thinking when working with CKEditor 5's model. It's not a plain-text any more and thinking about it as about textarea's content will not work for you.